# BIM360Docs API Export Document with markup not working?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

[image]

As shown in the image, I have tried API provided by BIM360 from the following link:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/export-pdf-from-docs/

But I am not able to run API '**Export files with markups**' and received an error as shown in the image.

I have also mentioned **project id** and **version id** which is used in API call.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please encode your version id to URL-safe string with [Uri.EscapeUriString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring?view=netcore-3.1). There are some invalid string for a URL in the version id.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to hear this issue persists. Could you share the final URL you passed to RestClient? It's hard for me to imagine it by the snapshot you posted. In addition, please add an extra request header parameter `x-request-id` while calling the API. Its value can be any valid string, but please give it a meaningful value, e.g. ClientId-RandomGuid. We can consult our engineering team to check backend log with the `x-request-id` you passed. We appreciate your cooperation and patience. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Eason, for your help, it worked for Plan Folder. Can we also export file with markup for "Project Files" Folder?